# Java: Get the name of my project from code

Tags: java

I'm trying to achieve what I thought would be a simple thing.

Suppose I have the following folder structure:

```
myProjectName/src/com/company/Class1

myProjectName/src/com/otherCompany/somePackage/Class2
```

I want to write a piece of code that if called from either Class1 or Class 2 will simply return **`myProjectName`**

So basically I just want to get the name of my Java project (not the current working directory!)

Couldn't find anything online.

I have looked at reflection, but with no luck.

Comment: Have you looked at [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) ?

Comment: Extensively, but with no luck

Comment: you can get the directory where your .class file is in, but there is no way,  **at execution time**, to find out where the source files were (as I know). The folder name were you put the source file is arbitrary, eventually just matters for the IDE, at compile time. To find the directory, I believe you can use the `ClassLoader`

Comment: I have added to the question that you did look at reflection. A show of effort is important here - people want to see that you tried. You could [edit] it further and show the actual code you tried when using reflection.

Comment: @GeorgeCimpoies also, maybe, to some degree, use the class path (see `System.getProperties()`) - but not really reliable. I also remember using the `ProtectionDomain` to get the JAR file of my source... `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()` - ok, to some degree using reflection

Comment: Thanks @CarlosHeuberger, System.getProperties() helped me to a certain extent, see the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple spoken: there is no good (built-in) way to achieve that.

You see, when you look at:

```
myProjectName/src/com/company/Class1
```

Only the **package** name com.company.Class1 is visible at runtime. There is absolutely **no** notion within the Java language that covers that `myProjectName` part.

In other words: that name is *meta* information. Yes, the answer by Carlos gives you a way to access that, but I still would consider that more of a **hack** than a solution.

A better approach: simply create a class like `ProjectInfo`, or maybe `ComponentInfo` that carries such information.

Meaning: don't rely on file system names. If you have something that belongs to a project/component/unit/... then make that "concept" part of your source code. The intention of the `ProtectionDomain` and `CodeSource` classes is much more about security and such things. It is not meant as "container" for such meta information as a "project name".

Answer (score 1):

Just found it, done 20 years ago. you can get the directory where the code is in by using:

```
getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

This was used to list in which JAR the compiled code was in. It should work for file system too. With some basic string, path or URL *juggling* you should be able to separate the correct component of the path.

*Also note that this is the location were the compiled code is in, not necessarily where the **source** code is/was in, that is, mostly not the project name - this will only work at development time. Please also read GhostCat's answer!*

Comment: it yields about the same output as System.getProperty("user.dir"), which is the current working directory. I still need to use hacks like substring and stuff to get the project name

Comment: the *hacks* is kind of obvious. "user.dir" is the actual working directory, from where the application was started, not exactly where the code is in

Comment: As written in my answer: I disagree at the overall idea how to use source code path names to identify units of meaning, but still upvoting your answer, as it definitely points out some interesting aspect of the JVM which is probably unknown to many people!

Comment: @GhostCat  I actually added a note about that And your answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone in the comment section!

What I have so far (but not 100% reliable) is:

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
int indexOfSrcFolder = workingDir .indexOf("src")

String pathToProject = workingDir.substring(0, indexOfSrc)
```

Comment: see comment on my answer, "user.dir" is not the correct property

Comment: Well you need to understand that project structure is not part of Java conventions. It might be coming from the eclipse world. That is why you wont find any direct solution your question. You would have to apply some hacks on your own to figure this out. After having found the working directory above you can do the following String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println(workingDir.substring(workingDir.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,workingDir.length()));  This will print exact project name at least on windows.